# Why does the other function take longer to run

Tags: performance, python-2.7, optimization

I have two functions:

```
def construct_heirarchy(csv_file):
    heirarchy = defaultdict(dict)
    for row in read_CSV(csv_file):
        row = edit_csv_row_data(
            row,
            translate_ttypes=translate_ttypes,
            include_countries=settings.GEO_COUNTRY.itervalues(),
            skip_headers=SKIP_HEADERS,
            translate_header=translate_header)
        if not row:
            continue
        pid, _id, ttype = map(row.get, ('pid', 'id', 'type'))
        if pid:
            heirarchy[pid].setdefault('target', []).append(_id)
        heirarchy[_id]['type'] = ttype
    return heirarchy
```

and

```
def extract_csv_data(csv_file):
    csv_data = dict()
    for row in read_CSV(csv_file):
        row = edit_csv_row_data(
            row,
            translate_ttypes=translate_ttypes,
            include_countries=settings.GEO_COUNTRY.itervalues(),
            skip_headers=SKIP_HEADERS,
            translate_header=translate_header)
        if not row:
            continue
        # yield row['id'], row
        csv_data[row['id']] = row
    return csv_data
```

I track time of these functions using time.time

```
Heirarchy -2.90870666504e-05
Extracting 1.49716997147
```

I don't understand why there is such a huge time difference. If I use second function as generator, time is

```
Extracting 1.90734863281e-06
```

But then I can't use csv_data.get

Could someone help me understand what is going wrong here and what is the optimized way to do this?

**PS**: CSV is 6.1 MB with 85263x7 length.

Comment: It's not obvious why there is a difference.  Why not try using the profiler to find out where the difference is?

Comment: @strubbly cProfile says the first one takes 2.32 sec while the other is taking 2.15 second. Btw is it taking more time than it should take to extract data from such a CSV?

Comment: That sounds like near enough the same - I'm not sure what you are expecting or asking now.

Comment: I was asking if 2.32 sec is time more than it should take to extract data from a CSV of given constraint?

Comment: It depends on too many variables but it sounds like it is the time your system takes and we have no reason to think it *should* be anything different.  Why should it?